# Server with osrm walk or foot profile for use in R?

Tags: r, openstreetmap, contour, osrm

Default server only runs the 'driving' profile, as per the documentation.

> To change the profile ("driving" is set by default and it is the only
>   profile available on the demo server), use the osrm.profile option:
>   options(osrm.profile = "name.of.the.profile")

Anyone know a (free) server that provides the 'walk' profile?

The [OpenStreetMap Wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) offers a number of suggestions, but I'm not sure which to go with. I really want something minimal/lightweight.

I need to run a small number of queries: Enough for me to debug my code, and maybe 30 more. I'm not programming an app. So setting up a local instance of osrm on my local machine seems like overkill. It's also a pain to do on Windows (I've spent hours trying), using the material [here](https://reckoningrisk.com/coding/2017/OSRM-server/) and [here](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/4941).

PS: Walkalytics is cool, but produces raster data when all I want (in the end) is a vector of a 1.25 mile isoline/contour/iso-distance.

Comment: If you are forced to stick with Windows then you can at least try to set up OSRM in a Linux VM.

Answer (score 1):

Since recently the [OSM website](https://www.openstreetmap.org) uses a OSRM server with foot profile that is run by [FOSSGIS e.V.](https://www.fossgis.de/).

Frontend example: `https://www.openstreetmap.org/directions?engine=fossgis_osrm_foot&route=50.68633%2C10.91200%3B50.68339%2C10.91385`

Backend example:
`https://routing.openstreetmap.de/routed-foot/route/v1/driving/13.7807085453224,51.0536161;13.7835429,51.0515885?overview=false&geometries=polyline&steps=true`

[About routing.openstreetmap.de](https://routing.openstreetmap.de/about.html) has some details about it but no usage policy. Please don't abuse it. If you have to perform large numbers of queries then either switch to a different instance or install your own OSRM server.

Comment: Pardon me for being dim, but how do I set that as the default server in R? options(osrm.server="https://map.project-osrm.org") doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ah, got it: options(osrm.server="http://router.project-osrm.org/")
iso <- osrmIsochrone(loc = punto, breaks = seq(0,10,1), res =50) ....no luck changing to 'foot' or 'walk' yet though.

Comment: 'object speed is not found' is what I get after: options(osrm.profile = "foot")...I'm uncertain that osrmIsochrone can support 'foot'.

Comment: Sorry for being not clear enough. You still configured R to use `project-osrm.org` but you have to use `routing.openstreetmap.de` instead. I updated my question.

Comment: As per rcarto's answer, looks like I have a version mismatch that prevents me from using it. :(

Answer (score 1):

`osrm` (the R package) follows closely the OSRM server versions.
`routing.openstreetmap.de` uses v5.14.1 of OSRM server whereas `osrm` package is tested against v5.22.0. Problems you encounter are likely to come from this difference of version.
Docker version of OSRM (v5.22.0) built with `foot.lua` profile file and using "walk" profile in R works fine.